# Docker on Windows does not support COPY --from?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-for-windows

I am trying to make use of this Docker construct:

> Optionally a name can be given to a new build stage by adding AS name
>   to the FROM instruction. The name can be used in subsequent FROM and
>   COPY --from= instructions to refer to the image built in
>   this stage.

But I get this message:

```
COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder869050639/-–from=build-env: 
no such file or directory
```

Is copying files from a previous stage supported on Docker for Windows 17.09.0-ce-win33 (13620)? This is the Dockerfile:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.0-sdk AS build-env

WORKDIR /app
COPY ./ ./
RUN dotnet build ProviderApi.csproj
RUN dotnet publish ProviderApi.csproj -c Release -r linux-x64 -o out

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.0-runtime-deps
WORKDIR /app
COPY -–from=build-env /app/out/ ./
EXPOSE 80
ENTRYPOINT ["./ProviderApi"]
```

Comment: Does running `docker info` confirm that the version *running* is what you think it is?

Comment: @larsks yeah, that reports the same version - Server Version: 17.09.0-ce

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that the destination directory was not present in the docker image of the final build stage. Here is the working Dockerfile for future reference.

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore-build:2.0.3-stretch AS build-env

WORKDIR /app
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet build ProviderApi.csproj
RUN dotnet publish ProviderApi.csproj -c Release -r linux-x64 -o out

FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:2.0.3-stretch
RUN mkdir /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out /app

ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:5001
EXPOSE 5001

ENTRYPOINT ["/app/ProviderApi"]
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried with lowercase "as"? (seems like a long-shot, I see examples of both around)

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.0-sdk as build-env
```

or the more basic

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.0-sdk

COPY -–from=0 /app/out/ ./
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried both but still the same result unfortunately: ```COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder977659490/-–from=0: no such file or directory```

Comment: What version of Docker are you using? 
Try updating the Docker version. That was the issue in my case!